# Conflict in rewrite rules htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search-product.php?st=basic&product=$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search-product-city.php?st=basic&product=$1&city=$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue is only one rule works. All three files are  there in the root directory. How to make all rules work. Thank you for help.

Comment: You should explain first what each rule tries to accomplish. And then at least say which one works so people doesn't have to guess it

Comment: The _actual_ issue here first of all is, that you apparently have thought this through very little. Your first and third rule match the exact same pattern - which makes absolutely no sense to begin with. Imagine, I am requesting `/foobar` - is that meant to be a product search term, or a user profile? Based on what magic did you think the server would be able to _guess_ that, at this point?

Answer (score 0):

To identify different PHP files, it requires a unique prefix in the htaccess rule in order to redirect to specific file. For e.g. for search-product page searchproduct. Now your web URL would be

```
https://DOMAINNAME.com/searchproduct/PRODUCTID.
```

Similarly, you can retrieve other pages as well. Try the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?searchproduct/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search-product.php?st=basic&product=$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^/?searchcity/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ search-product-city.php?st=basic&product=$1&city=$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^/?profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$3 [L]
```

with this, you can add as many as **htaccess** rules you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but now site is not working this is the error Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

Comment: @Rahulk I have updated the code. There was a missing forward slash in front of prefix string. Try updating your htaccess

Comment: You have a `$3` backreference in the 3rd rule (copied from the OP). However, the regex `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` (2nd rule) is ambiguous since the hyphen is used as a delimiter between _product_ and _city_, yet (according to the regex) it can also appear within a _product_ and _city_ - it may be possible to simply remove the hyphen from the character class, but this needs to be resolved by the OP. (Ideally, the OP needs to provide additional information as to the URLs and values permitted - as requested in comments on the question.)